# Rename package name in android using commands

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

I want to change package name of an android project/apk so that i can have different version's of an application.

For this i have gone through some stackoverflow' questions for this { [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862138/how-can-i-change-the-application-package-name-for-an-android-app-via-command-lin) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287018/changing-application-package-name-in-custom-ant-build-step)}. My project is build with gradle. In these stack's answer's i was not cleared where to change in [roject's build.xml or sdk's build.xml.

Is this possible to change package name with "–rename-manifest-package" and release application on google play store? or i need to do somthing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For different version, change version on gradle file and make another apk then release it on google plays store. There is an option on google store it should be release new version or something like that.

However, it is not possible to change current application's package name which is on google play store.

If you cannot do, I'll try to add step by step guide.

EDIT:

At first you need to change your app's version in here which is `build.gradle(Module: app)` [image]

and then you need to create new signed apk since you want to publish it;

[image]

After creating signed apk you need to access your developer account and click APK section first and then upload new version of your application.

[image]

Comment: can you please add steps for renaming package name?

Comment: @Jennifer I've added steps, you can take a look.